# py2exe: Including an adjustable input file

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have a question regarding py2exe. I have scripts according to the following structure:

```
input.py
main.py
extra1.py
extra2.py
output.py
```

I think the naming is obvious, but to explain: I run main.py, this requires input.py and also calls on other scripts extra1.py and extra2.py. Afterwards it produces output.py.

Now I tried to make an executable out of this using py2exe. It all went well, I made the exe, it produces the output.py. However, the input.py was taken into the exe and I can't adjust it and run the .exe again.

Is there any way to set this up so that I can change my input file??

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to use `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Not yet. Should pyinstaller be able to do what I ask?